# Spring Auth Server doesn't authorize HTTP requests to secured endpoints by the passed Bearer token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server, oauth-2.1

## The key point

I am developing an application in **Spring Boot 3.1.0** using the **Spring Authorization Server** to implement an OAuth 2.1 server for Auth Code Flow with PKCE.

The OAuth works perfectly, but as soon as I continued to work on the service API part and secured it, my application refused to authorize incoming http requests to API endpoints with the Bearer token passed in the header.

## The main question

How to secure my REST API endpoints with Bearer token authentication in this single-module web-server?
Is it possible? What I should to do?

## The test case

Spring application logs:

```
# I try to exchange OAuth code for an access token
23:16:44.991 [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/token
23:16:45.059 [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.a.w.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder authentication to OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken

# And then I try to use this token for default OAuth provided endpoints (result: 200 OK)
23:17:16.212 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /userinfo
23:17:16.217 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST http://localhost:8080/oauth2/introspect
23:17:16.221 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
23:17:16.222 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{token=[2Jd2M-Pq3Cx8We9gKVpfosvAnNGjprCJoyA6-gHOH3t2_cbpVaGsmGkgJ1n9wzam_kvvL4cthCUwSCNRWrfm_uGZJUtFWJjL_jaaKla0p37MDwkPbrGGhoJOGLeGDSrC]}] with org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter

# Also for opaque token introspection (result: 200 OK)
23:17:16.227 [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/introspect
23:17:16.294 [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.a.w.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder authentication to OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken
23:17:16.307 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
23:17:16.308 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
23:17:16.320 [nio-8080-exec-6] .s.r.a.OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider : Authenticated token
23:17:16.320 [nio-8080-exec-6] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to BearerTokenAuthentication [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionAuthenticatedPrincipal@49bc387c, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_user:read, SCOPE_user:write]]

# After that I try to send request to my REST API controller (result: 401 + redirect)
23:17:43.504 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/user/get
23:17:43.504 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
23:17:43.504 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 9FC445DE02E5AA86CF6C7D898290112F
23:17:43.505 [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to team.flow.server.api.controller.UserApiController#getUser(Long, Authentication)
23:17:43.505 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/api/user/get?continue to session
23:17:43.505 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/auth/sign-in
23:17:43.512 [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /auth/sign-in
23:17:43.512 [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
23:17:43.512 [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to team.flow.server.auth.controller.AuthFrontController#handleDefaultRequest()
23:17:43.512 [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /auth/sign-in
23:17:43.512 [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/auth/sign-in", parameters={}
23:17:43.512 [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to team.flow.server.auth.controller.AuthFrontController#handleDefaultRequest()
23:17:43.513 [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Postman console screenshot for the last request:
[image]

## The source code

Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final List<String> FLOW_OAUTH2_SCOPES = List.of(
            "openid",
            "user:read", "user:write"
    );

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final FlowAuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler;

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/auth"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        ))
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .opaqueToken(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/error", "/flow-web/**", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/complete").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/logout").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/oauth2/code").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_user:read")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_user:write")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .maximumSessions(1))
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/auth/sign-in")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/sign-in")
                        .successHandler(authenticationHandler)
                        .failureHandler(authenticationHandler)
                        .usernameParameter("email")
                        .passwordParameter("password"))
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new FlowUserDetailsService(userRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient flowClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("")
                .clientName("")
                .clientSecret("")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/code")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/auth")
                .scopes(scopes -> scopes.addAll(FLOW_OAUTH2_SCOPES))
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                        .requireProofKey(true)
                        .build())
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE) // yes, I use opaque tokens here
                        .authorizationCodeTimeToLive(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(3))
                        .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(14))
                        .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                        .build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(flowClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }
```

REST API Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserApiController {

    private final UserApiService userApiService;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(@RequestParam(name = "id", required = false) Long userId) throws ApiException {
        if (userId < 1) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        User user = userApiService.getUser(userId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(UserModel.constructFrom(user));
    }

    @GetMapping("/meta/get")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserMeta(@RequestParam(name = "id", required = false) Long userId) throws ApiException {
        if (userId < 1) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        UserMeta userMeta = userApiService.getUserMeta(userId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(UserMetaModel.constructFrom(userMeta));
    }

}
```

Application config:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/${DATABASE}
    username: ${USERNAME}
    password: ${PASSWORD}

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

    open-in-view: false

  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        opaquetoken:
          introspection-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/introspect
          client-id: my_client_id
          client-secret: my_client_secret

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    '[org.springframework.web]': DEBUG
    '[org.springframework.security]': DEBUG
    '[org.springframework.security.oauth2]': DEBUG
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: DEBUG

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        same-site: lax

  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
    path: /error
```

Part of maven project configuration:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf Extras: Spring Security 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I also checked the contents of FilterChains in processing requests for OAuth endpoints and my REST API endpoints. In the latter case, there was nothing related to OAuth or Bearer token authorization, unlike the former. Maybe that's the problem, but I don't know how to tell the web server to authorize the request with the Bearer token.

Comment: new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login") If we dont want to use this and want to use rest endpoint with username/password what type of entry point that will be ? anyidea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to secure my REST API endpoints with Bearer token authentication?

With [resource server configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html)

#### How to do it in an application already containing client conf?

Both the authorization server endpoints and the ones exposing Thymeleaf pages require OAuth2 client configuration in which requests are secured with sessions (and require CSRF protection).

To have REST API endpoints secured with access tokens (and without session, CSRF protection, login or logout), define a third security filter-chain dedicated to resource server endpoints.

To keep your `defaultSecurityFilterChain` with OAuth2 client config as default, change its order to `@Order(3)`, and insert a `resourceServerFilterChain` with **`@Order(2)` and a security-matcher like `http.securityMatcher("/api/**")`** so that it only matches REST API routes and lets the `defaultSecurityFilterChain` process all requests that were intercepted by none of the security filter-chains with lower `@Order`.

You might refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for resource server configuration and applications with both OAuth2 client and OAuth2 resource server configuration (but nothing there about Spring's authorization-server, as I'm using other solutions as OpenID Providers).

Comment: Thank you a lot!
The solution can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/SoKnight/397ee1928b121c72c9d2dd254e153232) :)

Comment: Glad it helped. You may add `http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))` to your resource server filterchain: sessions are useless with access token (and use resources). Actually, you should disable CSRF protection only with  STATELESS SessionCreationPolicy. By the way, nicely detailed question.

Comment: @SoKnight, I'm glad you were able to get this working with @ch4mp's help. I will mention that I'm not in favor of setting up opaque token introspection such that the authz server calls its own introspection endpoint. In so doing, every request to the authz server is doubled with a 2nd request to itself. This could also very easily result in a deadlock situation if the thread pool becomes exhausted, which could only be broken by socket timeouts (if configured). I'd prefer to see a custom `OpaqueTokenIntrospector` that uses `OAuth2AuthorizationService` to perform introspection instead.

Comment: In the above code they are using thymleaf page for login page where he puts credentials. But if i want to use rest call without using thymleaf how the implementation be then ? as I want to use angular and from there i want to send username/password. Will please guide me on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76802882/spring-boot-3-1-spring-security-6-1-oauth2-grant-type-authorization-code-grant

You can check the query here

Answer (score 2):

You should notice that in the PKCE approach, no client-secret is used because the purpose of PKCE is to not store any client-secret in the front-end application because of the security issues.
By using PKCE, every time the client sends a request to the authorization server to obtain the authorization-code, a new hash code is generated to verify the client instead of using client-secret.
you can search for challenge-code and code-verifier on internet to get more information about hash codes that are generated to verify the client instead of client-secret.